# Comparar X fecha, que no sea anterior a 2 meses de la fecha actual - PHP

Tags: php, datetime

siempre me complico con las fechas y no se porque...

El caso de hoy, es que quiero comparar una fecha X y validar que esta no sea anterior a 2 meses a partir de la fecha actual.

Hasta ahora tengo esto, pero no me resulta lo de -2 months.

```
<?php

$fecha1 = "2021-10-31";
$fecha2 = "2021-07-01";

$comparo = new DateTime($fecha2);
echo $comparo->format('Y-m')."</br>";

$filtro = new DateTime($fecha1);
echo $filtro->format("Y-m")."</br>";
echo $filtro->modify("-2 months");

if ($comparo < $filtro) {
    echo "Anterior a dos meses </br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php) para saber la diferencia en meses entre dos fechas dadas.

Por ejemplo:

Si se trata de comparar `$fecha1` y `$fecha2`:

```
$fecha1 = "2021-10-31";
$fecha2 = "2021-07-01";
$dateOne = new \DateTime($fecha1);
$dateTwo = new \DateTime($fecha2);

$outPut=($dateOne->diff($dateTwo)->m > 2) ? "+ de dos Meses" : "- de dos Meses";
echo $outPut;
```

**Salida:**

```
+ de dos Meses
```

Si se trata de comparar alguna de las fechas con la fecha actual:

```
$fecha1 = "2021-10-31";
$fecha2 = "2021-07-01";
$dateOne = new \DateTime($fecha1);
$dateTwo = new \DateTime($fecha2);

$now = new \DateTime();

$outPut=($dateOne->diff($now)->m > 2) ? "+ de dos Meses" : "- de dos Meses";
echo $outPut;
```

**Salida:**

```
- de dos Meses
```

Comment: Trato de comparar la fecha1 (que uso como filtro), con la fecha2 que es la que se valida. Se comparan los meses solamente, por eso es que hay que cambiarle el formato a la fecha y considerar solo "Y-m"

Comment: @Excorpion en el enunciado de la pregunta dices que el objetivo es saber si han pasado más de dos meses entre las fechas. ¿Cuál es el inconveniente entonces? Si hay diferencia de años no importa, el intervalo tomará eso en cuenta también.

Comment: O sea solo es que le aplique el formato correcto y ya ?